# how resolve "sudo npm install" issues on MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, installation, sudo

Some time ago i've tried to update npm using `sudo npm install` on my Mac,
so the update didn't work and now i can't Run any of my npm progects.
after this problem i tried to solve it search some answers on npm forum, and i've found a discussion where a developer said "never use `sudo npm install`, in particular on MacOS".
so my question is

1. **how can i fix this problem without Formatting my pc if possible**
2. **why using sudo with npm command is a bad idea ?**

---

I'm sorry for my bad english, but i try hard to do my best.
thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an article about this issue that also walks through some solutions to managing node/npm versions without using `sudo`: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92

I'll try to summarize here.

First of all, if you're using MacOS, I highly recommend using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install system node if you haven't done so already. You should be able to run `brew install node` (which will also install `npm` and `yarn`) without using sudo assuming you've gone through the homebrew setup properly.

If you want to manage multiple versions of Node, I highly recommend https://github.com/tj/n as a tool. `nvm` is also very popular, but I prefer `n`. I walk through how to install and manage `n` in my article, but someone has also created a tool to help you through this: https://github.com/mklement0/n-install.

You can also take a look at [this part of my 2015 article on the same topic](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3#4b7c) to potentially help you with issues you might face from having run `sudo npm install` in the past. You might try `sudo rm -rf node_modules` in your project followed by `npm install` (*without* sudo).

Similarly, you may have to do something akin to `sudo rm -rf $(npm prefix -g)/{bin,lib/node_modules}` in case you globally installed node modules with the wrong prefix. Just be aware that this *will* remove libraries you installed with sudo before, so you will have to install them again.

In addition to the issues you're running into, a key reason why you shouldn't use `sudo npm` anything is because `npm` commands including `install` have the ability to run arbitrary scripts including ones that are downloaded from the registry. You don't want to give root permissions to something that runs arbitrary scripts!

Comment: @MiladRezazadeh which command do you regret running? In case you downvoted my answer, maybe there is a misunderstanding that I can clear up.